# Find the order of a differential equation in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, ode

I have a differential equation defined in Sympy (0.7.6.1), for example:

```
>>> y = Function('y')
>>> x = Symbol('x')
>>> y0 = y(x)
>>> y1 = y0.diff(x)
>>> y2 = y1.diff(x)
>>> eq = y2 - 2*y1 + y0
>>> eq
                      2      
         d           d       
y(x) - 2*--(y(x)) + ---(y(x))
         dx           2          
                    dx
```

I would like Sympy to tell me the order of the equation. I found nothing in the documentation. I faintly hoped that `degree` might work, but it doesn't:

```
>>> degree(eq)
1
>>> degree(eq, y)
0
```

Context: For pedagogical purpose, I've written a solver for constant-coefficient linear homogeneous ODEs. It finds the characteristic equation and solves it with Sympy's `roots`. Currently I have to pass the ODE order by hand next to the ODE itself, which is inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ode_order`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.deutils.ode_order). This gives you the order of the differential equation with respect to a function:

```
>>> ode_order(eq, y)
2
```

Comment: Thanks. It is documented in the Solvers module, not in ODE, which makes it harder to find.